# How to split words in line by comma, each with new line and matching indentation level?

Tags: vim, vi

I saw this keystroke combination once, but i can't recall how to do it and can't find it again. It was max 3 keys, or just my sweet dream of such useful thing. For example i have line:

```
foo, boo, yee,
```

And after this operation i want to have result like this:

```
foo,
boo,
yee,
```

Comment: this kind of question is very easy to google for, I would try that first

Comment: it is unlikely you could do this in 3 characters without a mapping or plugin. With those, you could make it down to 0 using autocmds (though I'd only know how to make that work every time you opened or saved a file)

Comment: I suggest you go to https://vimgolf.com/ and try out a couple of those, they will help teach you some very very sneaky ways to do this and more in very few keypresses. I doubt anyone actually uses the editor quickly on a daily basis in the same way as some of these solutions do, but nevertheless it is full of hidden gems.